# Load denied by X-Frame-Options

Tags: php, firefox, iframe

I have a pool of videos in my own server and another company is providing me the geoloc service in a video player that they developed. The problem is that I'm trying to load a simple  iframe of my provider just like this:

```
<iframe src="http://myvideoplayerprovider.com/videos/198" width="620px" height="360px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The iframe with the video shows up without a problem in Chrome and Safari. However in Firefox the console is giving me this error and is not showing anything on the browser:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.mydomain.com/ does not permit framing by http://subdomain.mydomain.com/gala8-foo/.
```

I have tried X-Frame-Options in my htaccess without a success and also this php line and nothing changed:

```
<? header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT'); ?>
```

Another ideas?

Comment: `GOFORIT` is not a valid value for the header. Try `ALLOW-FROM http://subdomain.mydomain.com/.

Comment: I can see a few similarly-titled questions in the Related sidebar to the right `---->`. Any good?

Comment: I told you that "I've already tried X-Frame-Options and this include the ALLOW-FROM option(which btw when I tried it, the site retrieves me internal server error). I also look this documentation that you mark as the "Proper one". I'm making the question because I haven't find the solution yet, not to upset you my friend.

Comment: You cannot include `http://myvideoplayerprovider.com` in your site in an iframe because that site has the X-Frame-Options enabled.  If you show us the EXACT iframe code and exact error we can verify this.  Your example above isn't consistent/exact cause the site you are trying to iframe isn't the same site being blocked. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score -4):

add this to web.xml for (both) applications

```
  <context-param>
    <description>Security precaution to prevent clickjacking: bust frames if the ancestor window domain(protocol, host, and port) and the frame domain are different. Another options for this parameter are always and never.</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.security.FRAME_BUSTING</param-name>
    <param-value>never</param-value>
  </context-param>
```